# Python - Delete comments in a Python code

Tags: python, comments

So i have to write a code that will delete every # comment in a Python code...
I have written a code (files method) but it deletes everything...
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

My code:

```
code=open("comm.txt","r")
for line in code:
if (line.startswith("#")):
    del line
code.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify a file that you open with `'r'` for reading. Also you should not modify an iterable as you are looping over it

```
with open('comm.txt', 'r') as code, open('comm_edit.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in code:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            out.write(line + '\n')
```

This will open a second file for writing, and write out any line that doesn't start with a `'#'`. Note that you are missing the fact that some people put comments next to the code

```
x = 5   # like this
```

Comment: @peter Any idea about how to delete comments next to the code?

Comment: A naiive way to do it would be `out.write('line.split('#')[0] + '\n'`

Comment: Please think about lines started with '#' placed inside multiline comment or docstring. They are not comments but your code will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
code = open("comm.txt","r")
code_back = open("new_comm.txt","w")
for line in code:
    if not line.startswith("#"):  #you dont need bracket here
        code_back.write(line)

code.close()
code_back.close()
```